# Flutter - google map, does not show my location

Tags: javascript, flutter, google-maps-markers

It seems to have written everything correctly but I can not understand why it does not show my location on the map.

Why is it not showing my location?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MyMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyMapState createState() => MyMapState();
}

class MyMapState extends State<MyMap> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  final LatLng _center = const LatLng(50.006406, 36.236484);

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    mapController.addMarker(
      MarkerOptions(
        position: LatLng(50.006406, 36.236484),
        infoWindowText: InfoWindowText('My Location', 'Office'),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Map'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          options: GoogleMapOptions(
            scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
            tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
            rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            compassEnabled: true,
            cameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: _center,
              zoom: 11.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you ask for the location permission?

Comment: But how to do it ?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name=
    "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name=
    "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

Paste these two lines in your Android manifest file.

And if you are run in emulator then switch to the physical device. because emulator can't show your current location.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to see your **current location** on the map, and enable the lower right **FAB** functionality that takes you there, make sure you have the property **myLocationEnabled** set to **true** on your GoogleMap Widget.

```
      [...]
      body: GoogleMap(
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          [...]
      )
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to provide an access to your current location
ios: Info.plist

```
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Application needs to access your current location</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Application needs to access your current location</string>
```

android: AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to use the  [location](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location) package of flutter in order to track the location of the user, and you need to add this function to your code

```
_getLocation() async {
    var location = new Location();
    try {
      currentLocation = await location.getLocation();

      print("locationLatitude: ${currentLocation.latitude}");
      print("locationLongitude: ${currentLocation.longitude}");
      setState(
          () {}); //rebuild the widget after getting the current location of the user
    } on Exception {
      currentLocation = null;
    }
  }
```

this function should be called in your `initState()` function as follows

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _getLocation();
    super.initState();
  }
```

and don't to forget to import the location package to your code,

```
import 'package:location/location.dart';
```

follow the installation guide of the location package as you need to add the location permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` for android and `info.plist` for iphone
the location package will be responsible for asking for location permission from the user at runtime

Hope it helps and good luck

Comment: Helpful answer for location in general but not the correct answer for the GoogleMap Flutter widget

Answer (score 3):

For Android: In debug mode and when your app is in development...you need to grant the location permissions manually in your phone applications settings and reloading your app in order to show the the "My location" button.

Comment: that worked to me. tks ...

Answer (score 2):

i suggest use below method.First you set LocationData currentLocation;
     var location = new Location(); in global.Second you create myCurrentLocation() method.And last use it initState() or button click.Don't forget import  in AndroidMainfest.xml and this classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2' android/build.gradle.

```
 LocationData currentLocation;
 var location = new Location();

 myCurrentLocation() async{
   try {
      currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
      print("locationLatitude: ${currentLocation.latitude.toString()}");
      print("locationLongitude: ${currentLocation.longitude.toString()}");
   } on PlatformException catch (e) {
   if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
      String error = 'Permission denied';
      print(error);
   }
   currentLocation = null;
}}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please provide some explanation about what your code does, it can help other users who might be looking for a solution to understand :)

Comment: First,sorry my poor English.You set LocationData currentLocation;
 var location = new Location(); this as global and after you create myCurrentLoacation method.And last you use method initState or any button click for getting current user loaction.

Comment: nothing to be sorry about, thanks for adding a little more details, now just edit you answer and add this info there.

Answer (score 1):

```
    GoogleMap(
onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
target: _center,
zoom: 13.0,
),
myLocationEnabled: true,
onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
```

Comment: @devpato this is not a link-only answer. It has code, and there isn't even a link. If you think this code is wrong or not useful, the correct action is to downvote.

Comment: @RobertColumbia i click on the wrong option so gave me. I meant this answer needs more explanation, not just the answer

Answer (score 1):

Not just myLocationButtonEnabled enough also you need to either

```
myLocationEnabled: true,
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

If you see everything is OK, just Uninstall the app and install it again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, its because i forgot to turn on location on device.